# What is the word for someone that is both good and bad at the same time?

Tags: single-word-requests

With a single word, how do you describe a person who has both great and bad qualities? They are not solely good or pure, but they're also not bad people. They have both positive and negative qualities. "Neutral" may come close, but that's a very broad definition.

Example:

*Donald Trump may have done some good things as president, but he has said some nasty things as well, making him a very [insert word] person.*

Comment: I am in college at Harvard and I myself have come across this situation many times and so I went to my English teacher and asked him how to make my own word in the dictionary. He told me and so I sent an email to the people at the Global Cambridge Dictionary organization, asking them to officialize the word, "Neutagonist", which means; A character or person whom is both an antagonist and a protagonist, or changes between the two throughout the story.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is ***morally ambiguous***:

> Donald Trump may have done some good things as president, but he has
> said some nasty things as well, making him a very **morally ambiguous**
> person.

from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moral%20ambiguity):

> moral ambiguity (noun) : a lack of certainty about whether something is
> right or wrong

Characters in literature and films (e.g antiheroes, sympathetic villains, lovable rogues, rakes etc.) are often referred to as “morally ambiguous” if they exhibit both a mix of good and evil in their actions and/or motivations.

Alternatively you could use **amoral**:

from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorality):

> Amorality is an absence of, indifference towards, disregard for, or
> incapacity for morality.

However this implies an absence of morality rather than a mix of both good and bad - which could be more apt description depending on the case - but since you asked for a mix of both good and bad, I will defer to my initial answer.

Comment: Amoral theoretically has the meaning of indifference, but is normally used negatively, e.g. to refer to someone driven only by self-interest without thought of morality - someone who tries to help other people without considering the legality might technically be indifferent to morality but would not normally be called amoral. But (morally) ambiguous is a good term.

Answer (score 0):

One might say "double-edged":

> Double-edged means has good consequences and bad consequences [Quora](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-word-for-something-that-is-both-good-and-bad-at-the-same-time%23)

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/double-edged) gives this too:

> Having two contradictory aspects or possible outcomes

Although this may not fit very well for a person.